# What does %A mean in F#?

Tags: f#, string-formatting

In the F# tutorial for Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 there was this code though slightly varied.

```
module Integers = 

    /// A list of the numbers from 0 to 99
    let sampleNumbers = [ 0 .. 99 ]

    /// A list of all tuples containing all the numbers from 0 to 99 andtheir squares
    let sampleTableOfSquares = [ for i in 0 .. 99 -> (i, i*i) ]

    // The next line prints a list that includes tuples, using %A for generic printing
    printfn "The table of squares from 0 to 99 is:\n%A" sampleTableOfSquares
    System.Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
```

This code returns the heading `The table of squares from 0 to 99 is:`.
Then it sends the numbers from 1-99 and their squares. I don't understand why `\n%A` is needed and specifically why it has to be an A.

Here are some other similar examples with different letters:

1. Uses `%d`

```ml
module BasicFunctions = 

    // Use 'let' to define a function that accepts an integer argument and returns an integer. 
    let func1 x = x*x + 3             

    // Parenthesis are optional for function arguments
    let func1a (x) = x*x + 3             

    /// Apply the function, naming the function return result using 'let'. 
    /// The variable type is inferred from the function return type.
    let result1 = func1 4573
    printfn "The result of squaring the integer 4573 and adding 3 is %d" result1
```

2. Uses `%s`

```ml
module StringManipulation = 

    let string1 = "Hello"
    let string2  = "world"

    /// Use @ to create a verbatim string literal
    let string3 = @"c:\Program Files\"

    /// Using a triple-quote string literal
    let string4 = """He said "hello world" after you did"""

    let helloWorld = string1 + " " + string2 // concatenate the two strings with a space in between
    printfn "%s" helloWorld

    /// A string formed by taking the first 7 characters of one of the result strings
    let substring = helloWorld.[0..6]
    printfn "%s" substring
```

This is making me a little confused because they have to have them letters or they won't work so could someone. Please explain the `%a`, `%d` and `%s` and any other if there are some and possibly what `\n` means as well.

Comment: How about reading [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee370560.aspx)?

Comment: Downvote. This question doesn't show any research effort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all explained on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/plaintext-formatting

F# uses reasonably standard format strings similar to C.

To summarise:

```
%s prints a string
%d is an integer
```

the only weird one is `%A` which will try to print anything

the `\n` is just a newline

Answer (score 0):

The symbols %A, %s und %d are placeholders. They will be replaced when the function printfn is called by the values of its parameters. Each placeholder expects a specific parameter type:

- %s - string
- %d - signed int
- %A - pretty-printing tuples, records and union types

Here are some examples which can executed in the F# REPL:

```
> printfn "a string: %s" "abc";;
a string: abc
val it : unit = ()

> printfn "a signed int: %d" -2;;
a signed int: -2
val it : unit = ()

> printfn "a list: %A" [1;2;3];;
a list: [1; 2; 3]
val it : unit = ()

> printfn "a list: %A" [(1, "a");(2, "b");(3, "c")];;
a list: [(1, "a"); (2, "b"); (3, "c")]
val it : unit = ()

> printfn "a signed int [%d] and a string [%s]" -2 "xyz";;
a signed int [-2] and a string [xyz]
val it : unit = ()
```

For more information on printfn und its placeholder I would recommend this site:

http://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/printf/

The string "\n" is not directly related to the placeholder. It inserts a new line.